# Handling variable number of "type parameters" in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

The goal is to create a completely type safe generic class such as a Table Class below which would allow to create a Table instance whose field types are given as type parameters (or any other possible means).

```
let userTable = new Table<number, string, string>(
  columnNames: ["id", "name", "address"],
  fields: [
    [0, "John", "225 Main"],
    [1, "Sam", "330 E Park"]
  ]);
let billsTable = new Table<number, Date, Date>(
  columnNames: ["custId", "invoiceDate", "dueDate", "balance"],
  fields: [ [1, new Date(), new Date()] ]);
```

The question is, with full type safety in focus, how would you define or implement such a generic type structure which could have unknown number of type parameters?

Comment: Still in discussion: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuples as your type parameters:

```
class Table<T extends string, U extends any[]> {
  constructor(columnNames: T[], fields: U[]) {
    /* Do something */
  }
}
```

If you provide type parameters explicitly, your arguments will be type-checked against them.

```
new Table<'custId' | 'invoiceDate', [string, number, Date]>(
  ['custId', 'invoiceDate'],
  [
    ['foo', 1, new Date()],
    ['bar', 2, new Date()],
  ]
)
```

Works with named parameters as well:

```
class Table<T extends string, U extends any[]> {
  constructor(configuration: { columnNames: T[], fields: U[]}) {
    /* Do something */
  }
}

new Table<'custId' | 'invoiceDate', [string, number, Date]>({
  columnNames: ['custId', 'invoiceDate'],
  fields:[
    ['foo', 1, new Date()],
    ['bar', 2, new Date()],
  ]
})
```

Comment: This gives compilation errors such as: "An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number' ". Also, try to add other methods or data members to the class and it complains!

Comment: That's because I left a broken index signature there. I wanted to see if keys can be established at the call site, but was reminded they cannot — _A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members._.